# Swift CoreMotion background saving battery

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I need to get users activity on background using Core Motion. I was able to reach this goal by adding the locations update as background mode and enable the background location fetch. But as I'm not interest in the user location, this results in waste of **battery** and a **blue sign** ( iPhone X ) that indicates the app is updating your locations in background.

Is possible to run core motion in background without update the location of the user in order to use less battery and not show the blue sign to the user??

Thank you really much in advance!!

**EDIT**

Example function code:

```
    private func startTrackingActivityType() {
  activityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) {
      [weak self] (activity: CMMotionActivity?) in

      guard let activity = activity else { return }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          if activity.walking {
              self?.activityTypeLabel.text = "Walking"
          } else if activity.stationary {
              self?.activityTypeLabel.text = "Stationary"
          } else if activity.running {
              self?.activityTypeLabel.text = "Running"
          } else if activity.automotive {
              self?.activityTypeLabel.text = "Automotive"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you are not interested in location then what kind of "Activity" you need to monitor? Are trying to get user steps or something else ?

Comment: activities like “walking”, “automotive”, “stationary” ecc.

Comment: please provide some code examples of CoreMotion and CoreLocation, you are using in your app

Comment: the code is the simplest possible and I use only the coremotion framework. I anyway edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be in background at all. Next time your app will launch, you can retrieve history for MotionActivity. In addition you can also get raw historical sensor data. But you should schedule it.

Details: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionactivitymanager?language=objc

Comment: Well, I have to send local notifications in background